# Katalon Studio: unable to resolve class com.kms.katalon.core.testobject.FindTestObject as FindTestObject

Tags: class, web-scraping, katalon-studio

I have written a scraping script which its supposed to copy data from one platform and write this data to a new excel. Katalon gives me an error about the class "import com.kms.katalon.core.testobject.FindTestObject as FindTestObject" and I don't know how to solve it (I am a beginner in programming).

This is the script:

```
import static com.kms.katalon.core.checkpoint.CheckpointFactory.findCheckpoint
import static com.kms.katalon.core.testcase.TestCaseFactory.findTestCase
import static com.kms.katalon.core.testdata.TestDataFactory.findTestData

import static com.kms.katalon.core.testobject.ObjectRepository.findTestObject
import static com.kms.katalon.core.testobject.ObjectRepository.findWindowsObject

import com.kms.katalon.core.testobject.FindTestObject as FindTestObject

import com.kms.katalon.core.checkpoint.Checkpoint as Checkpoint
import com.kms.katalon.core.cucumber.keyword.CucumberBuiltinKeywords as CucumberKW
import com.kms.katalon.core.mobile.keyword.MobileBuiltInKeywords as Mobile
import com.kms.katalon.core.model.FailureHandling as FailureHandling
import com.kms.katalon.core.testcase.TestCase as TestCase
import com.kms.katalon.core.testdata.TestData as TestData
import com.kms.katalon.core.testng.keyword.TestNGBuiltinKeywords as TestNGKW
import com.kms.katalon.core.testobject.TestObject as TestObject
import com.kms.katalon.core.webservice.keyword.WSBuiltInKeywords as WS
import com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.WebUiBuiltInKeywords as WebUI
import com.kms.katalon.core.windows.keyword.WindowsBuiltinKeywords as Windows
import internal.GlobalVariable as GlobalVariable
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys as Keys
import java.util.Arrays as Arrays
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement as WebElement
import com.kms.katalon.core.testobject.ConditionType as ConditionType
import com.kms.katalon.core.testobject.TestObject as TestObject

import com.kms.katalon.core.testobject.TestObjectProperty as TestObjectProperty
import org.openqa.selenium.By as By
@Grab(module = 'poi', version = '4.1.2', group = 'org.apache.poi')
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook as XSSFWorkbook

WebUI.openBrowser('')

WebUI.navigateToUrl('https://www.odoo.com/it_IT/web/login')

WebUI.setText(findTestObject('Object Repository/Page_Login  Odoo/input_E-mail_login'), 'EMAIL---')

WebUI.setEncryptedText(findTestObject('Object Repository/Page_Login  Odoo/input_Password_password'), 'PASS---')

WebUI.click(findTestObject('Object Repository/Page_Login  Odoo/button_Accedi'))


TestObject tableObject = findTestObject('/html/body/div[1]/main/div[1]/div/div[1]/table')

List<WebElement> righeTabella = WebUI.findWebElements(tableObject)

List<WebElement> arrayName = new ArrayList<String>()

List<WebElement> arrayEmail = new ArrayList<String>()

for (WebElement riga : righeTabella) { //ciclo per ogni riga della tabella
    WebElement link = riga.findElement(By.tagName('a')) //trova il collegamento <a> per ogni riga 
        

    WebUI.click(link) //apre il collegamento della riga
        

    WebElement nameSpan = link.findElement(By.xpath('.//span[@itemprop=\'name\']')) //Ricerco il campo span 'name'
        

    String nameText = nameSpan.getText() //copio il campo span 'name'
        

    arrayName.add(nameText) //aggiungo ad arrayName il valore del nome appena copiato
        

    WebElement emailSpan = link.findElement(By.xpath('.//span[@itemprop=\'email\']')) //Ricerco il campo span 'email'
        

    String emailText = emailSpan.getText() //copio il campo span 'email'
        

    arrayEmail.add(emailText) //aggiungo ad arrayName il valore del email appena copiato
        
}

Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook()

Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet('Dati')

for (int i = 0; i < arrayName.size(); i++) {
    // Popolamento del file Excel con i dati dell'array
    String nameExcel = arrayName.get(i)

    Row row = sheet.createRow(i)

    Cell cell1 = row.createCell(0)

    cell1.setCellValue(nameExcel)

    String emailExcel = arrayEmail.get(i)

    Cell cell2 = row.createCell(1)

    cell2.setCellValue(emailExcel)
}

// Salvataggio del file Excel
FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream('C:/Users/orien/OneDrive/Desktop/excel-lead-odoo.xlsx')

workbook.write(fileOut)

fileOut.close()

workbook.close()

WebUI.closeBrowser()
```

And this is the error:

Test Cases/Test 1 lead odoo FAILED.
Reason:
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
file:/C:/Users/orien/Katalon%20Studio/Odoo%20leads/Scripts/Test%201%20lead%20odoo/Script1687957429899.groovy: 8: unable to resolve class com.kms.katalon.core.testobject.FindTestObject
@ line 8, column 1.
import com.kms.katalon.core.testobject.FindTestObject as FindTestObject
^

1 error

```
at com.kms.katalon.core.main.ScriptEngine.getScript(ScriptEngine.java:199)
at com.kms.katalon.core.main.ScriptEngine.run(ScriptEngine.java:194)
at com.kms.katalon.core.main.ScriptEngine.runScriptAsRawText(ScriptEngine.java:119)
at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.runScript(TestCaseExecutor.java:448)
at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.doExecute(TestCaseExecutor.java:439)
at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.processExecutionPhase(TestCaseExecutor.java:418)
at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.accessMainPhase(TestCaseExecutor.java:410)
at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.execute(TestCaseExecutor.java:285)
at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseMain.runTestCase(TestCaseMain.java:144)
at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseMain.runTestCase(TestCaseMain.java:135)
at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseMain$runTestCase$0.call(Unknown Source)
at TempTestCase1689002556348.run(TempTestCase1689002556348.groovy:25)
```

I tried to import the class in "build.gradle" but nothing changed.

Answer (score 1):

The required class `com.kms.katalon.core.testobject.FindTestObject` seems not being recognized by the script.

Try to resolve the issue by checking the following points:

1. Make sure you have the necessary Katalon Studio libraries `com.kms.katalon.core.testobject` are listed in your `requirements.txt` file (located in the src/user directory) or in the section: `"external_dependencies"` in the `__manifest__.py` file (located inside your custom module). You can check the project's dependencies or libraries configuration to ensure that the required libraries are included.
2. Check the Katalon Studio documentation to ensure that it is properly installed and configured.
3. Check the version compatibility between the Katalon Studio version you are using and the libraries you are importing. Incompatibility between versions can cause issues.